# Is there any tool which can be used directly to create primefaces UI web page.

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I am new to primefaces and i want to create one web page with all css and form including buttons and all other stuff. Is there any tool in which we can drag and drop these components and apply css to them , so that we dont have to waste time in changing css everytime.

Comment: NetBeans has a Chrome Extension which lets you "Propagate changes done in the CDT back to the NetBeans IDE and save them". That might help a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the MyEclipse Visual JSF Designer:

https://www.genuitec.com/products/myeclipse/learning-center/web/myeclipse-visual-jsf-designer-overview/

Comment: Did you try PrimeFaces in this?

Comment: Indeed it seems to be only working with jsf HTML and jsf Core elements.

Comment: And most likely only 2.0 tags and not 2.2. IDE's are imo superfluous with rapid deployment and things